# Can I use my test environment merchant ID and keys to test a flex microform post?

Tags: cybersource

I'm getting started understanding what's required for Cybersource's Flex Microform integration. But to start with, I'm hoping to be able to see a valid response using my merchant ID, shared secret key and the general key that comes with generating the secret on the cybersource api reference page: https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#flex-microform_key-generation_generate-key

This is using the HTTP Signature method and ChasePaymentech (default) processor.

If I use the default settings they supply and choose to do a test POST to here https://apitest.cybersource.com/flex/v1/keys?format=JWT&

The JSON response is good with no complaints of authentication.

If I try to do the same POST with my test environment merchant ID and keys I generated in my merchant environment here: https://ubctest.cybersource.com/ebc2/app/PaymentConfiguration/KeyManagement the POST response will return a 401 with this JSON:

```
{
"response": {
    "rmsg": "Authentication Failed"
}}
```

Is this developer.cybersource.com site a valid place to perform this kind of test? Are there any other steps I need to do in the merchant account to have this Authenticate?

Comment: Could you tell me if you were able to figure out the solution? Removing ?format=JWT& from the end point resolves the issue, but keyId returned is encoded

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started on figuring out the CyberSource Flex Micro Form code out myself and it's pretty straight forward from what I can see. If you don't have the proper SDK already pulled in, you can fetch it from https://github.com/CyberSource

I had to use Composer to fetch all the dependencies but once I did, I was able to load up the microform checkout page in my browser window successfully. Make sure you edit the ExternalConfiguration file with your credentials that you setup in CyberSource.

The apiKeyId value is the value you can find in your CyberSource account under Key Management. This is the value with the dashes in it.

The secretKey value is the value you should have downloaded from CyberSource that is your public key. This is the value without the dashes and probably has a few slashes / in it.

That's all I had to do in my setup to get the first successful authentication / token on my end.